# How to free memory allocated by a local variable from the caller function in C?

Tags: c, malloc

I have a function like this below and I would like to free memory allocated by the `temp1` variable in the caller function.

```
// Code to insert element at Nth position
void Insertion (int num, Node **head)
{
    // I can't free this variable in this function because 
    // it will be used in future to navigate through the list. 
    // I would like to avoid global variables as well.
    Node *temp1 = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)); 
    temp1->data = data;
    temp1->next = NULL;

    Node *temp2 = *head;
    for (int i = 0; i < position - 2; i++)
    {
        temp2=temp2->next;
    }
    temp1->next = temp2->next;
    temp2->next = temp1;

    return 0;
}
```

The caller function looks like this below

```
int main(void)
{
    Node *head = NULL;

    Insertion (30, 1, &head);
    .....
    .....

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know what are my options here?

1. Should I be changing the return type of `Insertion` to `void *` from `void` and then free the function? I have a strong feeling that I am doing something invalid here.
2. Should I passing temp1 as a parameter? (it would overcomplicate things, so i'd like to avoid this approach)

Comment: It's impossible to say if you don't show more code. What kind of data structure is `Node`?

Comment: You can't without a garbage collector. Just `free` it explicitly.

Comment: Free it in the function `delete(Node** head)` which you are going to write soon.

Comment: It looks like you are creating a linked list. You are allocating the memory by calling malloc. When you are done with the memory, you free it by calling free. To do this you need a pointer to the allocated memory. When you add the node to the list, you hold the pointer value in temp1 until you get it into the right place in the list. When you remove it, you may need a variable to hold the pointer value in after you remove it from the list so that you can use it to call free.

Comment: @klutt I have added more code.

Comment: Looks like a linked list. There are tons of examples out there on how to implement them

Comment: @klutt Most of the ones I have looked at either use global variable OR have a memory leak.

Comment: @AviBerger I am trying to free the allocated memory from main() which is the caller function. I am not sure of the best way to do this.

Comment: Guys, I have added more information to my question. Sorry about skipping on the information.

Comment: Are you ever removing nodes from the list before the program ends? If you do this, you free each node when you remove it and are done with it as @Yunnosch has commented. If there are still nodes in it when you are done with the list,  you go through the list and delete each node, being careful not to lose the pointers to the remaining nodes before you free them.

Comment: @AviBerger I was not removing the nodes individually after adding them. It makes sense now. Thank for your replies. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to free a linked list.

```
struct Node {
    void *data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void free_list(struct Node *head)
{
    if(head->next)
        free_list(head->next);
    if(head->data)
        free(head->data);
    free(head);
}
```

Comment: oh, so i will have to create a new function to explicitly go through each item in the list and deallocate it. Thank you.

Comment: @numbersinmyhead You don't have to, but I see no reason to not do it.

Comment: I should, shouldn't I? I would have a memory leak if I dont free it.

Comment: I mean that you don't have to write a separate function, but there's no reason to not write a separate free function.